# How do I properly structure this Dart async code?

Tags: dart

I'm still learning Dart and OOP and can't quite get this right. The problem is that `_batch.addAll()` executes before `_invDetails` is populated from the inner ForEach because of the delay from the query. How do I structure this properly?

```
Future<Response> exportAccpac() async {
    final Map<String, dynamic> _inv = {'inv': []};
    final Map<String, dynamic> _invDetails = {'invDet': []};
    final Map<String, dynamic> _batch = {};

    final _qExpenses = Query<UserCompany>(context);
    _qExpenses.where((e) => e.company.id).equalTo(companyId);
    _qExpenses
        .join(object: (e) => e.user)
        .join(set: (u) => u.expense)
        .where((d) => d.date)
        .lessThanEqualTo(date);

    final _expenseList = await _qExpenses.fetch();

    _expenseList.forEach((e) {
      _inv['inv'].add(
        {
         // a bunch of stuff here using e
        },
      );

      e.user.expense.forEach((userExpense) async {

        final _qGlCode = Query<GlCode>(context)
          ..where((g) => g.user_type.id).equalTo(_userTypeId)
          ..where((g) => g.company.id).equalTo(companyId)
          ..where((g) => g.expense_type.id).equalTo(userExpense.expense_type.id);

        final _glCodes = await _qGlCode.fetch();

        _invDetails['invDet'].add({
        // a bunch of stuff here using glCodes
        });
      });
    });

    _batch..addAll(_inv)..addAll(_invDetails);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally avoid the use of `forEach` - especially with `async`. Restructure the code as follows:

```
  for (var userExpense in e.user.expense) {
    final _qGlCode = Query<GlCode>(context)
      ..where((g) => g.user_type.id).equalTo(_userTypeId)
      ..where((g) => g.company.id).equalTo(companyId)
      ..where((g) => g.expense_type.id).equalTo(userExpense.expense_type.id);

    final _glCodes = await _qGlCode.fetch();

    _invDetails['invDet'].add({
    // a bunch of stuff here using glCodes
    });
  }
```

This has the effect of performing the GL code queries serially, whereas previously you were kicking them off in parallel but with no way to wait for them to each finish. (To do that you'd have used `Future.wait`, but that shouldn't be needed here.)

You can replace the outer `forEach` with a `for` too.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The issue here though is that, since we are `awaiting` the query (which returns a future) the `for` loop needs to be `async` which is not possible. So, unless I'm missing something, this solution won't work either.

Comment: I've played around with this dropping `await` and using `.then()` and made some progress, but I'm still getting a problem with the outer loop completing before the inner loop completes. I'll keep trying. 

Also, I'm interested in why you say to generally avoid `forEach` since they both seem to do the same thing.

Comment: No. They don't do the same thing. `foreach` takes a closure, which, if it is async, returns a future. So the closure code will almost certainly execute in a later event loop. The other common mistake people make with foreach is to put return statements in them, expecting them to break from the outer loop, whereas that just returns from the closure. Hence the advise to avoid.

Comment: If also avoid then, as await code is generally more readable. To back to wait, add some more print statements and update the question with the results so far.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I got it working once I replaced the outer `forEach` with a `for` loop (as you said). I didn't realize there such a difference between the two. Learning a lot.

Answer (score 0):

you could put your forEach under an async function and return _inv to eventually become like this:

```
final _expenseList = await _qExpenses.fetch();
final _inv = await _yourNewFunction();
_batch..addAll(_inv)..addAll(_invDetails);
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm pretty new to this so still not clear. What would `_yourNewFunction()` look like? How you fit it into the code above?